# What is causing the 'Object Required' error with BorderAround() method?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a border around a range of cells using a range object. `Borders()` works but `BorderAround()` doesn't work, and I can't explain or figure out why since they both should modify a range object.

I get the error `Object Required` running the following code on the third line.

```
Set Figr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FIGURES")
Figr.Range("B31", Figr.Range("B31").Offset(9, 5)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
Figr.Range("B31", Figr.Range("B31").Offset(9, 5)).BorderAround.LineStyle = xlThick
```

Comment: `Borders` is a property while `BorderAround` is a method. Also, you are using the wrong argument (`LineStyle`). Try `.BorderAround Weight:=xlThick`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I see, thank you! That worked. I tried something similar before and it didn't work but must have been some other typo... appreciated!